# What does an if (number) return?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I seem to be having a hard time understanding what this does to my code?

```
const $counters = $('.js-item-counter')
if($counters.length)
{

}
```

What would this if statement return?

I can tell that the value is 1, but does this make sense?

I am trying to fix some frontend issues, and ran into something like this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript, `0` is a *falsey* value. Anything other than `0` is considered `true`.

So what your code is doing is, it is making sure that the `$counters` is present in the DOM because if it were, it would give the length of > 0.

`.length` property tells you how many elements of the given selector are present in the DOM. If it is 0, then the element isn't present. If it is more than 0, then the element is present and you can act upon it as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple test to see if any elements of that class exist. Using length of a jQuery object is the most common jQuery approach to count matches in the collection

If it is anything other than zero it is truthy and zero is falsy

There used to be a [`size()`](https://api.jquery.com/size/)  method but that was deprecated and if you read in it's docs it tells you to use `length` instead

Answer (score 1):

*length* coerced to *true* for any *length* other than 0 and *false* for 0:

```js
console.log(
  !!0,
  !!1,
  !!10
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The if statement will return true or false based on the condition.
If $counters.length > 0, it will return true and if block will be executed. Otherwise, it will return false and block won't be executed.

Answer (score 1):

It returns true if the number inside the if statement is greater than or equal to 1 and false if it is 0.

Answer (score 1):

if the target element is stand for integer that having initial value of 1, then you should do this way

```
if($counters > 1)
{
//note length is only for checking of element existance
}
```